# Javascript change global variable on div Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to change global var value on div hover.

When I **hover** on Class `.mehover` or `.mehoverAnother` the class '**hideplease**' will be added to `.mehide` or `.mehideAnother`.  When on **hoverOut** remove the class `.mehide` or `.mehideAnother` but delay the removal of a class by 2s and if each time I hover on `.mehover` or `.mehoverAnother` change the **timetolive** variable value to 0.

see my code below:

**Javascript**

```
var timetolive = 2000;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.meHover').hover(function() {
        //code here to change the timetolive var value 
        //the .mehide or .mehideAnother should hide immediately by changing the timetolive var value to 0
        $('.mehide').addClass('hideplease');
  }, function() {
        setTimeout(function(){ $('.mehide').removeClass('hideplease'); }, timetolive); //delay removal of class
  });

  $('.meHoverAnother').hover(function() {
        //code here to change the timetolive var value 
        //the .mehide or .mehideAnother should hide immediately by changing the timetolive var value to 0
        $('.mehideAnother').addClass('hideplease');
  }, function() {
        setTimeout(function(){ $('.mehideAnother').removeClass('hideplease'); }, timetolive); //delay removal of class
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="meHover">hoverme</div>
  <div class="meHoverAnother">other hoverme</div>

  <div class="mehide"></div>
  <div class="mehideAnother"></div>
</div>
```

jsfiddle sample here https://jsfiddle.net/pqn01e5h/9/

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve, but if you want to restart counting to "live", `setTimeout` returns timer object, which you can pass to `clearTimeout` function to "cancel" it.

Comment: I just need to clear the timetolive var when I hover on .mehover or .mehoverAnother

Comment: You mean `timetolive = 0;`?

Comment: Yes I mean clear the variable to 0

Comment: Have you tried using `timetolive = 0;` :D?

Comment: When I hover on div change the global variable to 0 on all running scripts

Comment: I'm not sure i understand, but if you do not want to change `timetolive` for all scripts, copy its initial value to local variable on document ready and then use that local variable instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code.

```js
var timetolive = 2000;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.meHover').hover(function() {
        timetolive = 0;
        $('.mehide').addClass('hideplease');
  }, function() {
    timetolive = 2000;
        setTimeout(function(){ $('.mehide').removeClass('hideplease'); }, timetolive); //delay removal of class
  });
  
  $('.meHoverAnother').hover(function() {
     timetolive = 0;
        $('.mehideAnother').addClass('hideplease');
  }, function() {
    timetolive = 2000;
        setTimeout(function(){ $('.mehideAnother').removeClass('hideplease'); }, timetolive); //delay removal of class
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.meHover {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.meHoverAnother {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
  margin: 20px 0 0 120px;
  position: absolute;
}
.mehide {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 60px 0 0 0;
}
.mehideAnother {
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  background: orange;
  position: absolute;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 60px 0 0 120px;
}

.hideplease {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="meHover">hoverme</div>
  <div class="meHoverAnother">other hoverme</div>
  
  <div class="mehide"></div>
  <div class="mehideAnother"></div>
</div>
```